# complete reload of webpage in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm developing a mobile web application , and I'm facing a serious issue with my project .I'm using external scripts for my project and sometimes if I made any changes in my current script, it didn't shows the change, because the browser loading older scripts from cache. Is there anyway to do a complete reload of webpage in asp.net. I cant ask my client to clear the cache, whenever I made a change in the script.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache-bust your reference by adding a querystring variable you update when needed:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js?version=123"></script>
```

Anytime the querystring variable is updated, the browser will download the script, irrespective of its cache.

Answer (score 1):

Update the reference to the script as well e.g.

```
    <script src="mycoollib.js?ver=001"></script>
```

Modify version number with each script modification (this could be automated if you also increment assembly version - in that case you can simple append assembly version).